# What situation would encourage me to use ENUMs over other alternatives?

Tags: mysql

For example, why would I use ENUM of '0','1' as opposed to having an INT(1) and set conditions in php?

Comment: INT(1) accepts from 0-9 , but enum (0,1) accepts only 0 and 1

Comment: insanity is one such situation

Comment: You should generally avoid using ENUM when the members are numbers. The MySQL documentation explains why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some people just need to create problems for themselves. They don't know it at the time. I recommend staying away from enum, like salmon left out on the summertime counter.

If you have codes, have a code table with full blown verbiage and Foreign Key Constraints. It's how the big boys roll.

http://komlenic.com/244/8-reasons-why-mysqls-enum-data-type-is-evil/

Answer (score 0):

The ENUM option is used, more descriptibos when developing your tables for example: **enum ('active', 'inactive')** instead of using zero or one, also can use it as **enum ('admin' editor ', 'client')**.

As I mentioned helps you be more descriptive and here about 6 months after touching your model, you look back and you must not guess that means one or zero. if not that just see it you realize that it serves the field.